# Factor of 4 appears in Jacobian coordinate transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, jacobian

I am was reading the wikipedia page on [metric tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor), when I saw something that was hard to grasp in the coordinate transformation section. This topic is a little bit uncomfortable to me, so maybe I have missed something, but there appears to be a factor of 4 that appears when working everything out by hand?

With r being a vector valued function $\vec{r}(u,\,v) = \bigl( x(u,\,v),\, y(u,\,v),\, z(u,\,v) \bigr)$, and with the following identity
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
E  &
F  \\
F  &
G
\end{bmatrix}
$$

the coordinate transformation is given by,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
E^\prime & F^\prime \\ F^\prime & G^\prime
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
E & F \\ F & G
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

With the following substitution in the coordinate transformation matrix,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime} & 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime} &
\frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 
B \\
C &
D
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The transformation then becomes,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
E & F \\ F & G
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\underbrace{A^2 E + 2 ACF + C^2G}_{E^\prime} & \underbrace{ABE + BCF + AFD + CDG}_{F^\prime} \\
\underbrace{ABE + BCF + AFD + CDG}_{F^\prime} & \underbrace{B^2E + 2BFD + D^2G}_{G^\prime}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

Plugging the values into the variables give the following expressions,

$$
\begin{aligned}
E^\prime &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime}
 \frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} 
+ 2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
+ \frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} \\
F^\prime &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} \\
G^\prime &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} + 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
\end{aligned}
$$

after simplifying by cancelling out similar factors in the numerator and denominator and summing the result, everything comes out to,

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{aligned}
E^\prime &= \frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial u^\prime}
 \frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}} 
+ 2 \frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}}
+ \frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}} \\
F^\prime &= \frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}} + \frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}} + \frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}}\frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial v^\prime} + \frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}} \\
G^\prime &= \frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}} + 2\frac{\cancel{\partial u}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial u}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}}\frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial v^\prime} + \frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\cancel{\partial v}}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}}\frac{\partial r}{\cancel{\partial v}}
\end{aligned}
$$

which then reduces to the following by adding the remaining terms,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
E^\prime &
F^\prime \\
F^\prime &
G^\prime
\end{bmatrix} 
=
4\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The Wikipedia article states (above equation 2') that the values of $E^\prime, F^\prime, G^\prime$ are in fact $
E^\prime = \frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}, \;\; 
F^\prime = \frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}, \;\;
G^\prime = \frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}
$

which then means that I get the following expression after simplifying my manual transformation above, and comparing it with the definition of $E^\prime, F^\prime, G^\prime$ from Wikipedia.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
E^\prime & F^\prime \\ F^\prime & G^\prime
\end{bmatrix}
\neq
4\begin{bmatrix}
E^\prime & F^\prime \\ F^\prime & G^\prime
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Questions**

1. How can I reconcile that this factor of 4 comes out? Is it just because the factor of 4 becomes irrelevant for an infinitesimal difference? Or have I made a terrible error somewhere?
2. Generally, how can I understand coordinate transformations when dealing with a Jacobian matrix, are they the same thing as a change of basis in linear algebra when we see the form $P^{-1}AP$? What is the significance here that this form is $P^\top AP$ with a transpose instead of an inverse? The Jacobian is highly unlikely to be orthonormal (right?), so the transpose is definitely not the inverse.

Comment: What following equality do you obtain? P.S. You are assuming $A,B,C,D$ all symmetric, which is beyond false.

Comment: I corrected the grammar to say that I am comparing the definition of $E^\prime, F^\prime, G^\prime$ from Wikipedia to my own derived expression, which are not equal. As far as I know, I am not assuming anything about $A, B, C, D$ being symmetric, the notation comes from the Wikipedia article and I believe they are all scalars

Comment: OK, you’re right that this is surfaces only and these are scalars. You’re missing dot products, but that doesn’t account for the 4. I’ll need paper and pencil to check your work. The transpose appears instead of inverse because this is the transformation of a bilinear form, not linear transformation.

Comment: Everything looks fine once you put in dot products , but there are no 4s. I don’t understand where you got the 4s.

Comment: Which dot products are you referring to that I am missing? The fours come from the fact that the partial derivative cancel out and the terms I made that sum over all the partials ends up being equal to 4

Comment: $r$ is a vector-valued function, so you’re dotting its partial derivatives to get scalars. Please edit your post to include a sample calculation. This is all chain rule and no partial detivatives cancel out.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by sample calculation and missing dot products. I have included the most detailed sample calculation which I know how to make in the original question.

Comment: No, you haven’t showed how you simplify $E’$ and get the factor of $4$. And you do need the dot products of vectors.

Comment: I added the simplification. I think it is clear that I have messed something up in this part, but I am still not sure where I went wrong

Comment: I think your simplifications are false. You can't just treat partial derivatives as fractions! This is not how the chain rule works. I would have to check more in details but I think you should too

Comment: So many misconceptions. You need to sit down and do some basic computations with actual functions. Your $\partial r/\partial u$ in the final edit makes no sense. The cancellations you're claiming don't work at all — you're demolishing the chain rule. You're basically saying $\partial r/\partial u' = \partial r/\partial u$ no matter what the functions are. Try the most basic examples.

Comment: I have added an answer that I think explains what the main problem is, that I was trying to add together terms of the total derivative even though they are not "like" terms and cannot be added together in that way. I see the error now, but I still do not see how "adding dot products" as you mentioned actually helps to get there, because I would have just made the same mistake with all the terms in the dot products as far as I can see. (e.g. $E^\prime$ would just be a sum over terms with the same fundamental error that I made).

Answer (score 1):

With r being a vector valued function $\vec{r}(u,\,v) = \bigl( x(u,\,v),\, y(u,\,v),\, z(u,\,v) \bigr)$, the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} \,\text{and}\, \frac{\partial r}{\partial v} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 3}$,  and with the following identity
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
E  &
F  \\
F  &
G
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} \\ \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It is convenient to view the matrix as an outer product as we will see, the coordinate transformation is given by,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
E^\prime & F^\prime \\ F^\prime & G^\prime
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} \\ \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned} = P^\top P
$$

$P$ then becomes the total derivative w.r.t. the new variables $u^\prime$ and $v^\prime$

$$
\begin{aligned}
P
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial u^\prime} 
+ \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial u^\prime} 
& \frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v^\prime}
+ \frac{\partial r}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial v^\prime}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime} 
& \frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\implies P^\top P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime} \\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial u^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime} &
\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}\frac{\partial r}{\partial v^\prime}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which gives the answer as specified in the Wikpedia page. The problem with the initial version is that I was accumulating terms of the total derivative which were not in fact like terms, but they were contributions to the total derivative from changes in the new variables $u^\prime$ and $v^\prime$.